# @CachePut does not work in @Configuration for pre cache

Tags: spring, caching

I was trying to use spring stater-cache in spring boot 1.3.5, everything works fine except pre load cache in @Configuration class.

```
Failed tests:
  CacheTest.testCacheFromConfig: expected:<n[eal]> but was:<n[ot cached]>
```

Please take a look at the code as below, if you met this before, please share it with me :)

```
@Component
public class CacheObject{

    @CachePut(value = "nameCache", key = "#userId")
    public String setName(long userId, String name) {
        return name;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "nameCache", key = "#userId")
    public String getName(long userId) {
        return "not cached";
    }

}

@Component
public class CacheReference {

    @Autowired
    private CacheObject cacheObject;

    public String getNameOut(long userId){
        return cacheObject.getName(userId);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SystemConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CacheObject cacheObject;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println("-- PRE LOAD CACHE BUT DIDN'T GET CACHED");
        System.out.println("------------------");

        cacheObject.setName(2, "neal");
        cacheObject.setName(3, "dora");

    }

}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = BootElastic.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CacheTest {

    @Autowired
    private CacheObject cacheObject;
    @Autowired
    private CacheReference cacheReference;

    @Test
    public void testCache(){

        String name = "this is neal for cache test";
        long userId = 1;

        cacheObject.setName(userId, name);
//        cacheObject.setName(2, "neal"); // this will make test success
        String nameFromCache = cacheReference.getNameOut(userId);
        System.out.println("1" + nameFromCache);
        Assert.assertEquals(nameFromCache, name);

    }

    @Test
    public void testCacheFromConfig(){
        String nameFromCache = cacheReference.getNameOut(2);
        System.out.println("4" + nameFromCache);
        Assert.assertEquals(nameFromCache, "neal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PostConstruct methods are called right after all postProcessBeforeInitialization() BeanPostProcessor methods invoked, and right before postProcessAfterInitialization() invoked. So it is called before there is any proxy around bean, including one, putting values to cache.
The same reason why you can't use @Transactional or @Async methods in @PostConstruct.

You may call it from some @EventListener on ContextRefreshedEvent to get it working